# has_many _through not working in Rails 3 after upgrade from Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, rails-3-upgrade

I have the following in my controller:

```
@campaign = Campaign.where(:id => params[:id])
@companies = @campaign.companies.sort { |a,b| a.name <=> b.name` }
```

The second line gives me an unknown method for `companies` and it worked fine before.

This is in my campaign model:

```
has_many :companies, :through => :contacts, :uniq => true
```

I tried the following and it still didn't fix it:

`has_many :companies, :through => :contacts, :uniq => true, :source => :company`

Answer (score 2):

```
@campaign = Campaign.where(:id => params[:id])
```

returns an array of results (probably just one item, but still an array). The "No Method Error" you're receiving is because the `Array` class doesn't have a `companies` method.

You either want to call `.first` on the result set:

```
@campaign = Campaign.where(:id => params[:id]).first
```

Or just use `.find`:

```
@campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: we can continue to use find?  I thought it was deprecated that's why I was changing it around....

Comment: As far as I know, only `find` calls using options are being deprecated. For example, you shouldn't use `find(:all, :conditions => ...)` anymore, but to find a single record by id, `find(id)` is still preferred.

Comment: [Here is an overview of what's deprecated](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface)